# what are the various properties that inflection indicates in words in various languages?

Tags: inflection

Whereas some types of inflection are common, such as gender, plurality, tense, etc., many languages are known to possess a very rich set of inflection semantics and/or agreement inflection features. Do you know of any resource that lists types of inflection across many different languages?

Comment: The [side bar on the Wikipedia page for Grammatical Categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_category) looks pretty thorough.

Comment: I wonder if there's any resource juxtaposing which of the properties are marked by inflection across a multitude of (mostly contemporary) languages

Comment: There is [WALS](https://wals.info/), but it's hard to accurately generalise across all of the world's 7000 living languages.

Comment: Is your use of "inflection" deliberate, or do you also include "derivation"? There are many cases where Theory A would label something inflection and Theory B would label it derivation, but also cases where there is agreement (the 3 specific items you listed).

Comment: There's a [handout for my Intro Ling class](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) that goes into what inflection is or can be, and how it's different from derivation, with examples from many languages.